# Documentation Beta - basic UX points

Tags: support, documentation

I've requested that a new topic is created for a particular tag and submitted an example to go with it.

- How does my new topic request get "approved"?
- It seems that I can "create" the new topic myself, but this only seems to do the same thing as requesting it.  Why have the option to Create it if it doesn't do anything different than requesting it?
- Was i supposed to have signed up for the Beta first?
- It says I can subscribe to be notified of changes.  How do I do that?

Comment: There _is_ documentation help in the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation It's the same help center as SO because it's _part_ of SO.

Comment: @Kendra:  Thanks.  I follow the logic but OTOH the Documentation gui manifestly doesn't work the same way as the rest of SO, plus what it say about Topic Requests is grimly ironic: "Topic requests are for users who do not have the the knowledge necessary to create the topic they are looking for. "

Answer (score 2):

Documentation on Documentation? Right here, in the Help Center:

[image: Where Documentation help resides]